# How to use TestRPC with NodeJS/Heroku

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, javascript

I have a node instance running testrpc on localhost:8545, I'm able to access it when running it from another node instance from the same computer and make web3 calls to it.

```
const port = (process.env.PORT || 8545);
server.listen(port, function(err, blockchain) {})
```

I understand with heroku, everything is mapped to port:80

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545")); 
// this works fine

web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://192.168.1.254:80")); 
// this should, but does not work
```

How do I solve this problem, or what PAAS would help me access a personal testnet running on a remote machine?

Answer (score 3):

Using heroku & docker :

> To build the Docker container from source:
>
> git clone https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc.git && cd testrpc
> docker build -t ethereumjs/testrpc .

Modify the docker file :

> CMD ["node", "./build/cli.node.js"]
> instead of
> ENTRYPOINT ["node", "./build/cli.node.js"]

Modify cli.js, line 64 become :

> port: argv.p || argv.port || process.env.PORT || "8545",

Create a new heroku app then

> heroku git:remote -a your_new_created_app

then :

> heroku container:login
>
> heroku container:push web

Et voila ! A fresh testrpc is running on port 80.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as above but:

```
CMD ["node", "./cli.js"] instead of ENTRYPOINT ["node", "./build/cli.node.js"]
```

In step 3, you edit cli.js so you should load it. If you try to edit cli.node.js
and keep step 2 the same, you will get `Error: Cannot find module './package.json'`